# Using georgian package in ubuntu

Tags: babel, languages, font-encodings

I would like to use LaTeX to format text in georgian. I have created a simple „Hello World”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{georgian}
\usepackage[T8M]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{georgian}
\begin{document}
გამარჯობა
\end{document}
```

When I try to generate a document however I get the following errors:

> You have used an old interface to call babel

and then:

> Package babel Warning: No Georgian font encoding has been loaded so
>   far. (babel)                A font encoding should be declared before
>   babel. (babel)                Default `T8M' encoding will be loaded 
>   on input line 73.
>
> ! I can't find file `t8menc.def'.

The document `t8menc.def` is present in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/georgian/t8menc.def` Is it the correct location? How can I make LaTeX find it?

Comment: You load `\usepackage{georgian}` twice. I'll test your MWE in a moment, but I assume it would be better to load `\usepackage[georgian]{babel}` once instead (after `fontenc` & `inputenc`).

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T8M]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[georgian]{babel}
\begin{document}
გამარჯობა
\end{document}` works a bit better for me. But I still get a warning about the encoding ...

Comment: I recommend you use Lualatex or Xelatex for Georgian language. This may help you avoid a lot of problems

Comment: Can kpsewhich find the t8menc.def file?

Comment: @AndrewSwann No it doesn't. It doesn't. It searches the index /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/ls-R but doesn't find the file.

Comment: Then you should rebuild that index file.